# Rails new credentials generate greater risk in case of master.key corruption?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Until now I was handling my app secrets the usual way :

- **In development**: my secrets are stored unencrypted in my secrets.yml file. The secrets.yml file is not commited to Github and
  stays on my computer.

  As per AWS  reccomendations I have roles that allow me to have development specific keys. This allows to restrain my development keys to certain functions that have a different scope than production keys.
- **In production**: My keys are stored on Heroku and called like `ENV["AWS_SES_KEY"]` in`config/environments/production.rb`.

I quite liked it because in case my computer is stolen, the development keys which then become corrupt can be erased at AWS without having to touch the production keys. And because the development keys can be limited to a certain scope of actions at AWS, it prevents any dangerous alterations (full bucket erasing ...)

Now we have credentials, if I am not mistaken, all keys (development and production) are inside the same encrypted file. The master key is the only environment key that is now seeded to Heroku. Though I still need this key locally to access the credentials. Then if my computer is stolen both development and production keys are corrupt and can generate a higher risk for my production app.

Is there something I am missing on the new credentials feature ? any way to avoid the above issue ?

What would be great is still using `secrets.yml` for dev keys and `credentials.yml.enc` for production keys, is it how it is intended ?

Answer (score 0):

As the [release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_2_release_notes.html#credentials) for Rails 5.2.0 states, the future intent is to replace `secrets.yml` and `secrets.yml.enc` with `credentials.yml.enc`:

> This will eventually replace Rails.application.secrets and the encrypted secrets introduced in Rails 5.1.

There's a very clear sense that `credentials.yml.enc` is meant to contain production credentials only because the Rails recommendation is to not have environment specific keys in it; i.e.,

```
# don't do this
development:
  # ...

production:
  # ...
```

As for the `config/master.key` "corruption" risk, I'm not sure how to answer that. The master key is only required when running in production mode. You can also store the master key in the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable. In development, you'd only need the master key if you wanted to edit `credentials.yml.enc`.

Comment: I agree, that Credentials are meant for Production keys only, but it is a good practice nowadays to have also distinct Development keys. If you do have Development keys, then there seem to be no other option than to store them in `credentials.yml.enc` at the moment. Also you say that the master key is only needed to edit the credentials file and should not be stored in Development. But then how can your development keys be  read ? You are getting confused with the fact that master key is not intended to be versionned in Git just like the old `secret.yml`

Comment: Whereas the `credentials.yml.enc` seems a good idea, it also seems that a specific solution for development keys should be considered. Actually the good old `secrets.yml` would do the trick, then the master key is not needed in development because the development keys stay unencrypted on your computer .. The all-in-one thing does not feel right to me

Comment: (1/2)

You misread what I said. In development, you would only need the master key to edit your `credentials.yml.enc` file since it's encrypted. This does not imply version controlling the master key. I also maintain that `credentials.yml.enc` is meant for production only.

If you're using `credentials.yml.enc`, then you still need the master key on some machine with push access to the repo for when you need to edit the credentials. You can decide which machine this is. This would also apply to encrypted secrets.

Comment: (2/2)

If you want to use secrets for development, then do so. I mentioned that the Rails devs are considering dropping secrets (unencrypted and encrypted), in case you weren't aware. They may decide against this, but I believe it should be kept in mind, and an alternative realized just in case.

All this being said, I personally don't use credentials or secrets because I'm content with environment variables. I also don't use Heroku, but this security concern is not Heroku specific.